# How do you decrypt the password in postgresql data base and python api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

1. I have to insert the username and password for login.
2. In python I encrypted the password by using `make_password()`.
3. In the database the username and password should be checked if they match to records they are able to login
4. Now the encrypted password should be convert to decrypt and have to check the password
5. How can I decrypt the password and where in python file or DB, Below the my python method

```py
def make_password(password, salt=None, hasher='default'):
    """
    Turn a plain-text password into a hash for database storage

    Same as encode() but generate a new random salt. If password is None then
    return a concatenation of UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX and a random string,
    which disallows logins. Additional random string reduces chances of gaining
    access to staff or superuser accounts. See ticket #20079 for more info.
    """
    if password is None:
        return UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX + get_random_string(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_SUFFIX_LENGTH)
    if not isinstance(password, (bytes, str)):
        raise TypeError(
            'Password must be a string or bytes, got %s.'
            % type(password).__qualname__
        )
    hasher = get_hasher(hasher)
    salt = salt or hasher.salt()
    return hasher.encode(password, salt)
```

My DB function

```sql
    select * from saas.saas_users sau
             where email_id = ip_email_id
             and password= ip_password
             and status =true
```

Comment: The idea with passwords is that hashing is not reversible: you hash the password entered by the user and see if it matches that stored in the database.

Comment: What I have to do is just getting a most simple way and encrypted data has decrypted..

Thanks in advance..